# Java depreciation table loop using sum of years

Tags: java

Three parameters are passed into this function to output a depreciation table. The first loop calculates the sum of the years, while the second loop will calculate depreciation for each year during the useful life of the item entered by the user. I'm having trouble coding the second loop so that it outputs the correct values under the headers of the above `System.out.println` statement. As is the loop won't run since it's the same loop as the first one.

```
public class Table
    {
    public void makeDepreciationTable( int useful_Life, double acquisition_Value, double salvage_Value )
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int year = 1;
        double accumulatedDepreciation;
        //  make a loop to calculate the sum
        while ( year <= useful_Life )
        {
            sum += year;
            year++;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is " +sum );
        // write the header of the table
        System.out.println(" Acquisition Value" + "" + " Salvage Value" + "" + " Useful Life" + "" + " Annual Depreciation" + "" + " Accumulated Depreciation" + "" + " Book Value" + "" +" Fraction");
        // make a loop
        while ( year <= useful_Life )
        {
            // calculate fraction
            double fraction = (double)year/sum;
            // calculate annualDepreciation
            double annualDepreciation = (acquisition_Value - salvage_Value) * fraction ;
            // calc accumulatedDepreciation
            accumulatedDepreciation += annualDepreciation;
            // calc bookValue
            double bookValue = acquisition_Value  - accumulatedDepreciation;
            // write one line of table
            System.out.println(acquisition_Value + "" + salvage_Value + "" + useful_Life + "" + annualDepreciation + "" + accumulatedDepreciation + "" + bookValue + "" + fraction);
            year++;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not clear what "sum" is supposed to represent. For example, if useful_life is 3, the first loop will cause sum to be 1+2+3=6. And why use a loop to do this calculation? A simple equation will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Because `year` has become equal to the `useful_Life` during the end of the first while loop, **you need to reset the `year` value to 1 again just before the 2nd `while` loop** as shown below:

```
year = 1;//reset year before 2nd while
while ( year <= useful_Life ) {
   //add your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add year =1 before second loop .

Because of first loop year value is incremented . But did not set it back to one before second loop